# Django Slice Queryset safely via GET-Attribute

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a list view like this:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class SomeListView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(SomeListView, self).get_queryset()
        limit = self.request.GET.get('limit', None)

        if limit:
            return qs[:limit]
        return qs
```

Now this is by far not an ideal solution to handle slicing functionality as this

- is open to TypeErrors (could be fixed, but requires yet another try exept)
- is not very elegant

Is there a better way to slice QuerySets via GET?

Comment: when you say it is not elegent, what do you mean? and also you will have to cast `limit` to `int` for it to work.

Comment: general idea is either use paginator like `?page=1` and you have the number of "limit" preset and returned per page, or use `start/offset`, then you only need to prefetch those "limitation" numbers and verfiy.

Comment: @MuhammadTahirButt the cast happens automatically, no need to add code. Also, I've got to put None in a variable and ask if it is None, then decide what to do - that's one variable and one if/else statement that could have been eliminated if QuerySets would have a .limit() functionality or something similar.

Comment: @Anzel: Interesting point. I try to figure out a solution based on this idea.

Comment: @Mohl, yea that's the norm how normally to deal with this kind of issue, at next stage you may want to look at caching strategy to improve the latency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use form to deal with all validation stuff and settings default values to limit field. I'd make a form

```
class SliceForm(forms.Form):
    limit = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1)
```

and then use it in your view like this

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(...).get_queryset()
    form = SliceForm(self.request.GET)

    if form.is_valid():
        return qs[:form.cleaned_data['limit']]
    else:
        return qs
```

Comment: I cannot use forms in this particular case. Also, your solution would add overhead where I try to find a way to reduce it.

Comment: I don't really think this is an overhead, since you will probably end up with using validation and checking limit argument anyway, and form is the best place to handle it. I'm just curious - why can't you use forms in your case?

Comment: I take everything back - a Form IS the way to go here. In my head forms were tied to ModelForms so strongly that I outright rejected the perfect solution for this problem on first sight. My apologies.